# Why does requirejs allow you to specify a string id?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In requirejs it is possible to define an anonymous module or to give it a string id. According to [this article](http://blog.crisp.se/2012/10/30/danielsundman/requirejs-providing-structure-where-none-exists), you would normally not use the string id:

> You would not normally use the id when you define your module. It is typically used by tools when optimizing a RequireJS application.

I currently define my modules anonymously and use `require.config.paths` for the mappings. What I don't understand is: why does requirejs allow you to specify string id's if they're not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does requirejs allow you to specify string id's if they're not needed?

They only are not needed if require can figure out what module it is that just called `define`. This is the standard when `require()` did load the script file that contains the module, whose name and path it knows.

However, the optimizer will put multiple modules in a single file, and there needs to be a different way to figure out what modules are `define()`d. From [the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename):

> These [names] are normally generated by the [optimization tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html). You can
>   explicitly name modules yourself, but it makes the modules less
>   portable -- if you move the file to another directory you will need to
>   change the name. It is normally best to avoid coding in a name for the
>   module and just let the optimization tool burn in the module names.
>   The optimization tool needs to add the names so that more than one
>   module can be bundled in a file, to allow for faster loading in the
>   browser.

Comment: So if a string id is not explicitly declared, requireJS will use the file location as the id, right? Which I guess is why files with a single `define` can leave out the string id, since it can be inferred?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Not sure whether it's explicitly mentioned in the docs somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer as to James Burke's motivations, but I can point out instances of its usefulness.

- Define your own single page "layer" for testing, using JSBin or JSFiddle. The following code can be easily executed without having to stand up endpoints for each module or to use r.js to create a layer.

  ```
  define('A',[], function(){ console.log('A loaded');});
  define('B',[], function(){ console.log('B loaded');});
  define('c',['A','B'], function(){ console.log('C loaded');});
  ```
- Define a "local override" for troubleshooting. Add a `define` right before your `require` to easily preempt  a module definition add a new module so you don't have to touch several files while you're working

  ```
  define('plugin/fancySelect',[], function(){/* ... */});
  require([ /* ... */], function(){
    // your main application code
  });
  ```

Comment: I accepted the other one since it was more of an immediate answer to my question, but this is great as an addition to that!